# Refund the bounty if no anwers recieved

Tags: support, bounty, unanswered-questions

I offered a bounty on this question: [Can I enable AHCI mode of the SATA controller when booting to Windows on a MacBook with Nvidia chipset?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/34981/12493) and didn’t get any answers. Now I think the amount should be refunded so if I get a useful answer, I can award those +50 to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bounties are not refundable by design; you get the full value of the promotion period for every bounty, whether there are answers or not.

https://apple.stackexchange.com/faq#bounty

If bounties were refundable, they could trivially be gamed, or used again and again on essentially unanswerable questions, etc.